# Timestamp guest/user added to Office365 group

Tags: sharepoint, azure-active-directory

How to find when and by whom a user was added to a Office365 group/SharePoint.

- Audit gave no activity of a specified user or the SharePoint folder.
- Case: A user was added tot a Office365 Group. we don't know by whom. There is only one group owner and a tenant administrator can add a member.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested in my environment

You can check the details of when and by whom the user is added to office 365 group by below options:

1. Login to Azure Active Directory --> Under Groups, select the group in which the user is added --> Go to Audit Logs

   You can check the details of when and by whom the user is added to office 365 group

[image]

2. Login to Graph Explorer and run the below query:

   **GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/auditLogs/directoryAudits**

[image]

Comment: Thank you RamaraoAdapa-MT, my Aduit did't get result because limits of 30 days limitation voor E3/A3 P1 license.  I was searching for a deepdive solution.

Comment: The only way to get these details is through audit logs